# PHP Get info from another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

How can I get a row's info from another table without having to `SELECT` each loop?

```
//get posts from "posts" table
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = :user_id");
$stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $userId);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo $row['post'];

    //get poster's full name from "users" table
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id = :user_id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':user_id', $row['poster_id']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result2 = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($result2 as $row2) {
        echo $row2['full_name'];
    }
}
```

how can I make this code more efficient and faster?

imagine if i have 1000 posts and each is posted by a different user. i need to get the full name of that user that posted the post. right now, i need to `SELECT` 1000 times because of those 1000 users. it seems so inefficient right now. how can i make it better?

I heard join might work? what are the solutions?

Comment: You are asking about Performance. I always feel the need to link this good Article when such a question comes up: http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/
So is there an actual problem you need to solve? Where exactly is the bottleneck? How likely does this data change (could you cache it)?

Comment: @Christopher imagine if i have 1000 posts and each is posted by a different user. i need to get the full name of that user that posted the post. right now, i need to `SELECT` 1000 times because of those 1000 users. it seems so inefficient right now. how can i make it better?

Comment: @MattiaDinosaur Can you please show an example?

Comment: show your table define

Comment: What have you investigated so far about "join"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM posts
JOIN users ON posts.user_id = users.id
WHERE posts.user_id = :user_id.
```

You are right, joining the users table onto your posts query will be faster.

Something else you can do to increase performance is to cache the results of your query in something like memcache and then clear the cache when a post is added or deleted.  That way you don't need to hit your db every time this data is needed.

Comment: ok but how would I access the variables? for example from `$row['post']` and `$row2['full_name']`

Comment: The same way, a joined query will just return columns from both tables.  So you won't need $row2 or the inner loop.  Everything will be available in $row.

Comment: I agree with Ryan Tiosto's solution. However you questions seem to be about SQL join, not so much PHP anymore. Forget the PHP side for a spell. You can not code the PHP before you understand the SQL: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: @RyanTuosto "Everything will be available in $row". Okay what if there is a column named `full_name` in both tables?

Comment: You should manually select column names instead of * and alias them like select posts.full_name as post_full_name, users.full_name as user_full_name

Comment: @RyanTuosto sorry im new to this. what do you mean?

Comment: The * in the select clause means select all columns.  Instead you can list the columns you want to select separated by commas like I mentioned

Comment: @RyanTuosto another question: Someone said this that if there is no matching rows in the `ON` clause, it will get filtered out. Any way to not filter it out?